# Error while using "using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;" with stl vector

Tags: c++, boost

while finding the inverse of matrix using boost library, when I try to use this 
 `using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;` 
 then the compiler shows an error that

> there is an ambiguity as there is a vector class also in boost library.

Any suggestions on how to overcome this.

Comment: Did you also say `using namespace std`;? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: yes I also used using namespace std:

Comment: The simplest and best solution is to not do that.

Comment: I had already wrote a huge code which is using the various stl libraries, can I do something that can save time or I have to edit the complete code

Comment: You should really fix your code.

Answer (score 3):

This is [the kind of problem that you can expect from using directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). The best solution is to simply not use them. You can mitigate the scope for errors by using them in very limited scopes (e.g. inside function definitions). Alternatively, you can use [namespace aliases](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias) to make your code more concise. For example,

```
namespace ublas = boost::numeric::ublas;
```

Comment: +1 for the namespace aliases as the cleanest solution to these problems. One of the most common aliases that I frequently see is `namespace bfs = boost::filesystem;`. An alternative would be to create aliases/typedefs for the most common types and `auto` to deduce as many types as possible.